# "cargo check -p node-template-runtime --release" error: failed to select a version for `signature`

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I'm working through how to [authorize specific nodes](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/authorize-specific-nodes/) with substrate but I get this error that I can't seem to fix so now I'm stuck. Had no problems building substrate-node-template but could there be an issue with my build? Running on WSL2 kali-linux.

````
error: failed to select a version for `signature`.
    ... required by package `ecdsa v0.14.4`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ecdsa-core = "^0.14"` of package `p256 v0.11.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `p256 = "^0.11.1"` of package `webrtc-dtls v0.7.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `dtls = "^0.7.0"` of package `webrtc v0.6.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `webrtc = "^0.6.0"` of package `libp2p-webrtc v0.4.0-alpha.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `libp2p-webrtc = "^0.4.0-alpha"` of package `libp2p v0.50.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `libp2p = "^0.50.0"` of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/devri/substrate-node-template/runtime)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/devri/substrate-node-template/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `>=1.5, <1.7` are: 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.6.2, 1.5.0

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `signature v1.4.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `signature = ">=1.3.1, <1.5"` of package `ecdsa v0.13.4`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ecdsa-core = "^0.13"` of package `k256 v0.10.4`
    ... which satisfies dependency `k256 = "^0.10.4"` of package `frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.28#ce10b9f2)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-support` of package `frame-system v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.28#ce10b9f2)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-system` of package `pallet-node-authorization v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.28#ce10b9f2)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `pallet-node-authorization` of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/devri/substrate-node-template/runtime)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/devri/substrate-node-template/node)`

```


Previously had this error:
error: failed to select a version for `libp2p`.
    ... required by package `sc-telemetry v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.42#bca8a29d)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-telemetry` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/devri/substrate-node-template/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.50.0` are: 0.50.1, 0.50.0

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/devri/substrate-node-template/runtime)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/devri/substrate-node-template/node)`

  previously selected package `libp2p v0.50.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `libp2p = "^0.50.0"` of package `sc-cli v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.42#bca8a29d)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-cli` (locked to 0.10.0-dev) of package `frame-benchmarking-cli v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.42#bca8a29d)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking-cli` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/devri/substrate-node-template/node)`

failed to select a version for `libp2p` which could resolve this conflict
```

 that was fixed by adding

```
libp2p = { version = "0.50.0", default-features = false, features = [
  'gossipsub',
  'kad',
  'identify',
  'ping',
  'mdns',
  'noise',
  'yamux',
  'tcp',
  'websocket',
  'dns',
  'request-response',
  'metrics',
  'tokio',
  'macros',
] }
```
````

to the runtime cargo.toml file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actual fix involved changing my dependencies to:

> [dependencies]
> pallet-node-authorization = { default-features = false,
> version = "4.0.0-dev" }
> codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec",
> version = "3.2.2", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
> scale-info = { version = "2.5.0", default-features = false, features =
> ["derive"] } libp2p = { version = "0.50.0", default-features = false}

And adding rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown